# How is it possible there is footage available of this incident?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america, marvel, captain-america-civil-war

In *Captain America: Civil War*, it is revealed that

> Bucky killed Tony Stark's parents.

How is it possible that there was any footage available of this event?

> Did HYDRA always record such incidents on video?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Warning: Spoiler level over 9000. This is effectively the bulk of the plot that wasn't already revealed in the trailers.

If you had watched the movie to the end and paid attention to when the revelation was made,

> the final screening of the footage showed the Winter Soldier shooting at the screen - an indication that this is a camera recording.  
>  Most likely, the incident was captured by a speed camera that just happened to be there. Ordered to leave no witnesses, the Winter Soldier thus destroyed it. He likely reported this to his superiors when he returned - HYDRA would then recover the footage and cover up to prevent any leaks, though they did not, apparently, destroy all traces of the footage permanently. 
>  The likely reason that Sokovian dude possessed the clip was because he hacked into SHIELD - formerly HYDRA's front for over half a century - and accessed its files to find something with which he could destroy the Avengers from within - and this clip is exactly what he needed.

Comment: THIS COMMENT IS A SPOILER, DON'T READ IT: Just FYI, Zemo didn't posses the clip until the very end of the film; everything he did up until that point was simply to learn the location of the Hydra base where the clip was stored and bait the Avengers into following him there so he could show it to them.

Comment: @DrRDizzle imo he has to either already have the clip, or know the clip exists. Do you know anything to proof that is true? Otherwise, doing everything he did while simultaneously finding the base without being sure there is something there that will definitely tear the Avengers apart is a futile endeavour of superhuman proportions...

Comment: I can't remember the exact words he says, but at one point he implies that he learned of the existence of the clip in the wake of the fall of SHIELD thanks to the files that Black Widow leaked all over the Internet. So he knew what the mission in question was, and he knew what that would do to the Avengers, but he didn't have the proof.

Comment: @DrRDizzle What I do remember is that he spoke about SHIELD's databases being not impossible to hack, given time and effort, implying he did so successfully. I've seen in another question that Cpt. USA himself knew because the HYDRA boss at SHIELD showed him footages of the Winter Soldier, one of which is the incident in question. This means the video is definitely in SHIELD's database, so...yeah

Comment: HUGE SPOILERS FOR REAL, DON'T READ THIS: Steve actually says that he didn't know for sure that Bucky killed Tony's parents. All Zola told him (well, more implied) in *Captain America: The Winter Soldier* was that Hydra were behind their deaths, and it isn't too much of a stretch for Steve to realise that it was probably Bucky who carried out the hit.

Comment: @DrRDizzle Steve doesn't just say that he doesn't know for sure, or imply that he suspected Bucky was behind it. He specifically says he didn't know it was Bucky. Zola talks about "Accidents will happen" while flashing a newspaper clipping of Howard Stark's death in relation to multiple incidents, and there's no reason shown for Steve to believe Bucky was part of that. He knows that Hydra was, he isn't shown to know that they used Bucky for this hit specifically.

Comment: @thegreatjedi I believe what's shown in Zemo's sniffing of Hydra intel is details that Bucky made the hit to retrieve the serum from the car. I don't think there's any evidence that he found the clip itself at the start - not sure where you're suggesting it's in SHIELD's database. He did have a grievance against the Avengers, but he also had a grievance against ANY enhanced people, and at this point he was the only one who knew about them. He may never have known that the clip itself existed until the very end.

Comment: It feels like it's not too much of a leap to go "Bucky works for Hydra, Hydra organised the hit on Howard Stark, Bucky is probably involved." Especially if Zola/Zemo knew the other  winter soldiers were active yet.