# Captain America: Civil War | Zemo's motives and influence

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america, captain-america-civil-war

I just felt there might be some plot holes around the Zemo character. Supposedly he did

> everything including framing Bucky,

so that all the Avengers would come to a place where

> he can make Stark watch the video of his parents death in the hope that would make him turn on the rest of the Avengers.

But how could he know that Stark (Iron Man) would even show up in that place?

And was Zemo the one who hired Rumlow in the beginning

> to steal the biological weapon,

if so how did that fit in his plan?

Comment: You're asking several questions at once here, and you should really simplify this into a single question to focus on. Also, at least one of these questions is a duplicate - this question addresses the video of the assassination: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/127034/how-is-it-possible-there-is-footage-available-of-this-incident

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Supposedly he did everything including framing Bucky, so that all the Avengers would come to a place where he can make Stark watch the video of his parents death in the hope that would make him turn on the rest of the Avengers.**

I think his primary objective throughout the movie was to obtain hard evidence that the Winter Soldier has killed Stark's parents, in order to turn Stark against the Winter Soldier and presumably Captain America. I don't think he necessarily *originally planned* to have them meet him in Siberia.

However, as events played out, he eventually decided that dropping the false trail of the inactive Winter Soldiers would likely lead the Avengers there.

**But how could he know that Stark (Iron Man) would even show up in that place?**

Rogers and Barnes arrive and state "[Zemo] got here a few hours before us." They then gear up and enter the base. Moments later Iron-Man arrives and joins them. Then they ride a noisy elevator down into the facility.

Assuming the Avengers took the bait of more Winter Soldiers, he would expect some of them to show up (maybe he isn't current on how many are imprisoned or paralyzed). The elevator opens and it is Barnes, Roger, and Stark, lucky him! At this point he decided to reveal himself and show Stark the tape, to get them fighting. Had they not arrived, he might have left the base and found a way to get the footage to Stark at a later time.

If Stark hadn't been there, he might not have revealed himself (*we may never know the truth*).

**And was Zemo the one who hired Rumlow in the beginning to steal the biological weapon, if so how did that fit in his plan?**

I don't think there is anything to suggest that is the case. That sequence of events was more designed to demonstrate that the Avengers cause a lot of collateral damage.

Comment: Zemo specifically calls room security to get them to come up and discover the dead body of the UN psychologist. It seems to be a clear indication that that play was done specifically to get that into the news to alert someone like Iron Man. I don't even think he necessarily expected Iron Man himself to turn up, but that whoever was on Bucky's side would turn on Bucky when that bit of news was revealed.

Answer (score 0):

Captain America, Winter Soldier and Falcon knew that the shrink wasn't the original shrink, but Iron Man didn't....they haven't told Tony that, actually Captain did, but Tony being Tony wouldn't listen.....When Zemo reached Siberia, he calls or he gets a call from the waitress and orders some food, the waitress discovers the dead body of the original shrink and the MASK of Bucky Barnes and it hits the news....In the helicopter to visit the colonel in some submarine prison, Tony read the news of the dead original Shrink and learn about Zemo trying to frame Bucky. Of course Tony did show the evidence to the colonel, but the colonel didn't believe it.....If the colonel did believe him and released all the avengers, I believe everyone would have gone to help Captain, including Iron Man. And Zemo would have got a Big Avenger fight again, this time with Iron Man having the intent to kill.

So Iron Man would have gone there once he got to know that he was wrong about Bucky and that Captain was right about Zemo.